# Javascript Timer should go on after Web Browser is closed

Tags: javascript, web-applications, timer

I have written the following code for a Javascript timer with a few validations.

```
function timedcounter(){
    time=time+1;
    t = setTimeout(function(){ timedcounter() }, 1000);
    display(time);
}

function starttimer() {
    var autotask=document.getElementById("Tasks").value

    if(autotask=="") {
        $("#errormsg2").show();
    } else {
        if(!timer_is_on){
            add_row_flag=1;
            var value=document.getElementById("startstopbutton").value
            if(value=="Start") {
                timer_is_on=1;
                value="Stop";
                document.getElementById("startstopbutton").innerHTML="Stop"
                $("#errormsg2").hide();
                timedcounter();
            }
        } else {
            add_row_flag=0;
            stoptimer();
        }
    }
}



function stoptimer(){
    clearTimeout(t);
    timer_is_on=0;
    document.getElementById("startstopbutton").innerHTML="Start"
    document.getElementById("disptime").value=null;

    finaltime(time);
    time=-1;
}
```

I wanted to know is there any way to keep the timer going even after the user closes the browser, as in when he reopens the webpage timer should show the time elapsed since he started the timer.

Comment: Absolutely no way to keep javascript running in a browser that isn't

Comment: I dont't think that is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three options:

1. Store the timer start time with timezone in [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) and on page reopen read it and continue where you left off
2. Use a web server and store user timer start times there
3. Store it in a [cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie)

Comment: 3. Store the timer data in a cookie?

Comment: I don't want to start from where I left off. I want to log the time even when the browser is closed. Like the website toggl.

Comment: You don't need to log the time, you need to log when the timer was started and then you can always calculate elapsed time with `timeNow-timeWhenTimerWasStarted`, the user doesn't need to know that you don't have a ticker in the background when the browser is closed

Comment: Thanks! Will try this suggestion